# findstr multiple search in one single output line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have multiple text files that contains 3 lines of information that I want to output as one single line for each file

Example

**File1.txt** contains

```
User: "John"
Date: "13-March-2017"
Time: "10.30am"
Remarks: "xcvsfas"
```

**File2.txt** contains

```
User: "Mary"
Date: "13-March-2017"
Time: "11.30am"
Remarks: "xerteyas"
```

My expected output is as follows

```
c:\temp\file1.txt:User: "John"; Date: "13-March-2017"; Time: "10.30am"
c:\temp\file2.txt:User: "Mary"; Date: "13-March-2017"; Time: "11.30am"
```

I tried
`findstr /s /i "user date time:" %inputfolder%\*.* > %outputfolder%\final.txt`

Comment: Have you considered using powershell?

Comment: unfortunately I am not familiar with that

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Code modified per *new specifications* posted in a comment in other answer... **`:(`**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "file="
(
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /S /I "user date time" %inputfolder%\*.*') do (
   if "!file!" neq "%%a" (
      if defined file echo !file!:!out!
      set "file=%%a"
      set "out=%%b"
   ) else (
      set "out=!out!; %%b"
   )
)
echo !file!:!out!
) > %outputfolder%\final.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I will also have a go at this

Comment: Aacini, thanks for editing my whole question block. How did you do what you did... especially the line betweek spacing ?

Comment: Aacini, apologies of over simplifying my problem, refer above comment to dcg

Comment: Mod ready, see my edit. You did not "over simplified" the problem, but posted entirely _different_ specifications! You **MUST** edit the question and add the _new specifications_ in it, including _real data examples_ that may include other different lines! Otherwise, the question have no sense ("why you posted different specifications of the _whole problem_ as a _comment_ under a _certain answer_ only?).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I am quite to new to this asking of help. I will try to redact some of the sensitive data and post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all your .txt are in the same folder and only them. Then I get the first three lines of each file and print them in one line by using the `set` command like:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd <files dir>
for /f %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    set "c=0"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do (
        set /a "c=c+1"
        if "!c!" equ "3" (
            set /p "=%%j" <nul
        ) else if "!c!" lss "3" (
            set /p "=%%j; "<nul
        )
    )
    echo(
)
popd
```

I tested with the input you gave and the result is:

```
User: "John"; Date: "13-March-2017"; Time: "10.30am";
User: "Mary"; Date: "13-March-2017"; Time: "11.30am";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you sire, I will try run it and feedback accordingly

Comment: I realise I was giving the simplified version of the input text. Your code seems to be counting the first 3 lines and stitch them together. Sorry for my oversimplifying the problem. Actually I am trying to use the findstr command to search through the entire text and pick out User, Time and Date 's entire line in one line for one text file. Please let me know I sounds confusing. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the files by a `for` loop and do the search individually -- like this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_LOCATION=."
set "_INPUTFILES=File*.txt"
set "_OUTPUTFILE=%~dpn0.log"

rem // Write everything into output file:
> "%_OUTPUTFILE%" (
    rem // Iterate over matching files recursively:
    for /R "%_LOCATION%" %%F in ("%_INPUTFILES%") do (
        rem // Initialise line string variable:
        set "LINE=%%~F:"
        rem // Search currently iterated input file for the keywords:
        for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /L /I /B "User: Date: Time:" "%%~F"') do (
            rem // Store found item:
            set "ITEM=%%L"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion in order not to lose exclamation marks:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Build line string and transfer result over `endlocal` barrier:
            for /F "delims=" %%E in ("!LINE!!ITEM!; ") do (
                endlocal
                set "LINE=%%E"
            )
        )
        rem // Return built line string:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo !LINE:~,-2!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The fields `User:`, `Date:` and `Time:` are returned in the original order they appear in every file.