# FINDSTR multiple search in one single output line (Revision 2)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

This is version 2 of the FINDSTR function for searching multiple key words and output them into one single line per file

File#1 - **CW_TESTDP3_9_13_0925.txt** contains below

```
User: "DanMac"  
Date: "Wednesday April 05 2017"      Part#: "CW_EVALTCAPDP3_9_13_37"  
Time: "09:25:57 AM"         Operator: "CALVIN"

Unit; Voltage; Power; Host; Grb1; grn2;    
1; 220; 390; 24; 2; 5     
2; 234; 340; 64; 11; 15     
3; 10; 904; 2443; 211; 115     
4; 320; 390; 24; 2; 5     

Total_Test_time : 35minutes 40seconds
```

File#2 - **BW_ENGDP3_8_13_232345.txt** contains below

```
User: "Jerry"  
Date: "Tuesday April 04 2017"      Part#: "BW_EENGDP3_9_13_37"  
Time: "10:15:57 AM"         Operator: "CALVIN"

Unit; Voltage; Power; Host; Grb1; grn2;    
1; 220; 390; 24; 2; 5     
2; 234; 340; 64; 11; 15    
3; 10; 904; 2443; 211; 115     
4; 320; 390; 24; 2; 5     
5; 24; 40; 4; 511; 154     
6; 103; 4; 2; 21; 125     
7; 345; 90; 4; 122; 53     

Total_Test_time : 45minutes 4seconds
```

Expected output

```
c:\temp\CW_TESTDP3_9_13_0925.txt:User: "DanMac"; Date: "Wednesday April 05 2017"; Time: "09:25:57 AM"; Total_Test_time : 35minutes 40seconds
c:\temp\BW_ENGDP3_8_13_232345.txt:User: "Jerry"; Date: "Tuesday April 04 2017"; Time: "10:15:57 AM"; Total_Test_time : 45minutes 4seconds
```

Comment: `findstr` is not able to extract portions of a line. You have to use a `for` loop - as described in all three answers of your previous question. Please show the code, you need help with.

Comment: Fine. And what is your question? Have you tried anything on your own, or do you expect somebody else to write code for you for free? You are not going to get your homework done on StackOverflow, you need to show your efforts first! By the way, this post is not even slightly better than your [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43223179) concerning `findstr`; you should have updated the other one rather than posting a new question...

Comment: Thanks Stephan for the edit. I have been using findstr function, but I am opening up, to see if there are other command that I should try out to better achieve the end output result

Comment: You should select one of the answers in _all_ your questions as "Best answer" via its check-mark. Doing that inform other users that the question was answered already and give rep points both for you and for the poster of the selected answer.

Comment: Ok got it. I will run both iterations and see which is best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd c:\temp
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I "User Date Time" *.txt') do (
   for /F tokens^=1-2delims^=^" %%c in ("%%b") do (
      set "file[%%a]=!file[%%a]!%%c"%%d"; "
   )
)
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set file[') do echo %%~Fa:!file[%%a]:~0,-4!
```

Comment: i have added `>> output.txt` to see the output file. working fine this code

Comment: If you want to create a new output file, enclose the whole `for` command in parentheses and use the standard `>` redirection instead of the append `>>` one (exactly as I did in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43232799/778560) at your other question). This avoids the need to delete the file before and makes the process run faster... BTW you need to also select an answer in such a question.

Comment: already selected answer that works for me. while I am trying out others. Your patience to answer my queries very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (??_*.txt) do (
  set "line="
  for /f tokens^=1^,2delims^=^" %%a in ('type "%%f" 2^>nul^|findstr "User: Date: Time: Total_Test_time"') do (
   set "line=!line!; %%a"%%b""
  )
  echo %%~ff:!line:~2,-1!
)
```

Comment: Will try it out Stephan

Comment: if it is not working, what are the things I should report back? I tried putting `pause` at various places to see where the error is but can't seem to be able to see the error syntax

Comment: for troubleshooting, remove `echo off` and don't run it by doubleclick, but start it manually from a `cmd` box.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\%1"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\%1"
SET "outline="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /b  "User: Date: Time: Total_Test_time" "%filename1%"') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=: " %%r IN ('echo %%a') DO (
  CALL :aparams %%s
  IF DEFINED parm2 (SET "outline=!outline!; %%r: "!parm1!""
   ) ELSE (
  SET "outline=!outline!; %%a"
  )
 )
)
>"%outfile%" ECHO %outline:~2%

GOTO :EOF

:aparams
SET "parm1=%~1"
IF "%~3"=="" (SET "parm2=") ELSE (SET "parm2=%~2")
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Expected syntax to run:

> *thisbatchname* filename

The `findstr` command filters out the key lines. Those lines selected are partitioned into the part before any colon or space to `%%r` and the remainder of the line after the first group of colons and spaces to `%%s`. The remainder is analysed by the procedure `:aparams` which saves the first in `parm1` and the second in `parm2`, but only if there is a 3rd.

This delivers sufficient information for concatenating the output, either the entire original line in `%%a` or the initial string in `%%r`,': ' and the parameter saved by `:aparams` in quotes; each prefixed by `;`.

Having assembled the line, output it, skippingg the first 2 characters (the initial `;` added by the accumulation mechanism)

Comment: don't want to use `>>"%outfile%"`?

Comment: @Stephan: User's choice. Would seem to want to create a new file rather than append, but who really knows?

Comment: Thanks Magoo for the explanation on how the code works.

Comment: Stephan, you brought out the append function that gave me an "ah ha" moment to better streamline my output